# No BAKE BUTTON in 2.92

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to upload a fluid animation to a render farm (rebus.net) but it says I have to do a FINAL bake. There is no FINAL bake button as far as I can see in 2.92, just the All bake button and Modular. I've tried Modular bake as well - no difference. Anyone come across this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Rich

Answer (score 1):

There has been a renaming. What before was *Final* has changed to *All*, while *Modular* stayed *Modular*. The difference between *Final* and *Modular* was, that with modular you had to bake data, mesh, noise etc. separately which allowed you to build the simulation step by step.

So if you had a high resolution and baking the data took long but was great, then you baked the mesh and the settings were wrong so it looked horrible, then you could rebake the mesh without having to rebake the fluid data.

*Final* assumes you've finished testing your settings and are ready to bake everything at once for a **final** simulation, not separate parts one after another - so *Final* bakes **all** of the simulation. I don't know the reason, maybe people were confused about what *Final* meant, so to clarify that all is baked together it was renamed to *All*.

But that's just a guess on my behalf. The result is the same, *Modular* let's you bake different parts separately, *Final* and *All* simulate everything completely with one bake.

In how far the Renderfarm is able to work with the simulation I don't know - but the baked data should not be different from *Final* to *All*.